# How I can create a graph of uniform circular motion - tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a graph of uniform circular motion like the one in the picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
           \def\numofpoints{2}
           \def\circpatt{{1, 1}} % 1 filled 0 empty
           \def\labelpatt{{1,2}}

           \node[circle,draw,minimum width=3cm] (bigc) {};
           \foreach \x in {0,...,\numexpr\numofpoints-1\relax}
           {
            \pgfmathparse{\circpatt[\x]}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax\def\mycolor{black}\fi
            \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,fill=\mycolor] (n-\x) at (bigc.360/\numofpoints*\x+180) {};
            \node (l-\x) at (360/\numofpoints*\x+180:2.5cm)  {\pgfmathparse{\labelpatt[\x]}$\pgfmathresult$};
           }
           \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (1.5);
        \draw[thick, blue, ->] (0,0) node[left, black] {O} -- ++(45:1.5) node[coordinate] (a) {} node[above right, black] {$A$};
        \draw[thick,green!50!black,->] (a) -- ++(135:1cm) node[right, black]{$\vec{v}_A$};
        \filldraw (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw (0.7,0.4) node {$\vec{r}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution which automatically calculates the proper angle for the "tangent" line without writing a lot of code.

**Mandatory gif!**

[image]

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\findtan[2][3]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\glen{#1/3*2}
    \node[coordinate, label={#2:$A$}] (p) at (#2:#1 cm) {};
    \draw[ultra thick, blue, ->] (c) -- (p);
    \path ($(c)!.5!(p)$) --++ (-90+#2:3mm) node[at end] {$\vec{r}$};
    \draw[ultra thick, green, ->] (p) -- ++(90+#2:\glen cm) coordinate (e); 
    \path (e) --++ (0+#2:4mm) node[at end] {$\vec{v}_A$};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\node[circle,fill, inner sep=2pt, label={left:O}] (c) at (0,0) {};

\findtan{60}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```